# Git Hooks to send value to Jira

Tags: github, githooks

Im using githooks post commit. Whenever I make a commit I want the post commit to execute in such a way that it sends values or information to the Jira server (URL address) which  will receive JSON values through post commit scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This git project tries to do exactly that: https://github.com/joyjit/git-jira-hook

You would use it by installing the hook and then referencing your jira ticket like this: "fixes #NNN"

anywhere in your git commit message, where "NNN" is the name of an open 
Jira issue.